# matplotlib fill in between step function

Tags: python, matplotlib

I need to plot a step function in matplotlib (because that's the correct interpretation of my data) and would like to fill between the x-axis and the step curve.
Something like `fill_between`, only that this one does not work with `drawstyle`.

See minimal example below:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(2)
x = np.arange(50)
y = np.random.rand(50)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(x, y, drawstyle='steps-post')
ax.fill_between(x, y, drawstyle='steps-post')   # does not work
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ax.fill_between(x, y, step='post')`. `fill_between` doesn't have the parameter of `drawstyle`.